# Wordpress filtering posts

Tags: php, wordpress, filtering, categories

I wanted to know if there is any chance so I can create post filtering like categories. For example to make a few sections like categories, one for location, month, city. So when I make a post check those filters and from the user site to filter the post from those checked items. I don't know if I was clear about my problem, Hope I was.

Thanks in forward.

```
 add_theme_support('post-formats', array('aside', 'gallery', 'link')); 
 /*i have also tried this method*/
 add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```